# Minimum Order Amount in magento

Tags: php, magento

Is there any way to get minimum order amount code in Magento,
i want to add it in custom field of my home page, please help me with this

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get with getStoreconfig

```
$amount = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount', $storeId);
```

pass `$storeId` if you have multiple store.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: where you want this value ?

Comment: Header section of the page

Comment: use this `Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount');`

Comment: it's not included currency rate to check at frontend

Comment: minimum store amount stored per store, so i think you can grab it from store object currency sybol

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set the minimum order amount in **System > Configurations > Sales > Minimum Order Amount**. By default the message will be shown in shopping cart when subtotal after discount is less than minimum amount.

You can see how they are doing it in `Mage_Checkout_CartController`

```
    $minimumAmount = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())
        ->toCurrency(Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount'));

    $warning = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/description')
        ? Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/description')
        : Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Minimum order amount is %s', $minimumAmount);

    $cart->getCheckoutSession()->addNotice($warning);
```